# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'epaysave_user'@'localhost'

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am running a website using Django. Below is my error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'epaysave_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

Below is what i have tried:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `epaysave_db_prod`.* TO 'epaysave_user'@'localhost'IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'MYPASSWORD';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Still i am getting the error.
Why is that?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE USER 'epaysave_user'@'localhost'` (leave out he password hash if you want but it should be harmless). You're quite sure you have the right password in the django configuration?

Comment: yes the password is correct in django config